# docker network freezing randomly

Tags: ubuntu, networking, docker

Sometimes , all network's of my dedicate server is freezing (ssh also not working). it's randomly repeated.

OS:  Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS

On server installed docker containers, and i see in **dmesg logs**:

```
[1568390.415464] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): veth70c3620: link is not ready
[1568390.415571] docker0: port 2(vethfd09262) entered forwarding state
[1568390.415575] docker0: port 2(vethfd09262) entered forwarding state
[1568390.415586] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): veth70c3620: link becomes ready
[1568390.453889] eth0: renamed from veth70c3620
[1568405.455565] docker0: port 2(vethfd09262) entered forwarding state
[1568490.807194] aufs au_opts_verify:1612:docker[22618]: dirperm1 breaks the protection by the permission bits on the lower branch
[1568490.839695] aufs au_opts_verify:1612:docker[25041]: dirperm1 breaks the protection by the permission bits on the lower branch
[1568490.873185] aufs au_opts_verify:1612:docker[25041]: dirperm1 breaks the protection by the permission bits on the lower branch
[1568491.213577] aufs au_opts_verify:1612:docker[25041]: dirperm1 breaks the protection by the permission bits on the lower branch
[1568491.248730] aufs au_opts_verify:1612:docker[25041]: dirperm1 breaks the protection by the permission bits on the lower branch
[1568491.292433] aufs au_opts_verify:1612:docker[22618]: dirperm1 breaks the protection by the permission bits on the lower branch
[1568491.544051] aufs au_opts_verify:1612:docker[22618]: dirperm1 breaks the protection by the permission bits on the lower branch
[1568491.571716] aufs au_opts_verify:1612:docker[22618]: dirperm1 breaks the protection by the permission bits on the lower branch
[1568491.605760] aufs au_opts_verify:1612:docker[22618]: dirperm1 breaks the protection by the permission bits on the lower branch
[1568491.858186] aufs au_opts_verify:1612:docker[25041]: dirperm1 breaks the protection by the permission bits on the lower branch
[1568491.885767] aufs au_opts_verify:1612:docker[25041]: dirperm1 breaks the protection by the permission bits on the lower branch
[1568491.919876] aufs au_opts_verify:1612:docker[25041]: dirperm1 breaks the protection by the permission bits on the lower branch
[1568492.164684] aufs au_opts_verify:1612:docker[25041]: dirperm1 breaks the protection by the permission bits on the lower branch
[1568492.197225] aufs au_opts_verify:1612:docker[25041]: dirperm1 breaks the protection by the permission bits on the lower branch
[1568492.233425] aufs au_opts_verify:1612:docker[25041]: dirperm1 breaks the protection by the permission bits on the lower branch
[1568502.618191] veth70c3620: renamed from eth0
[1568502.653605] docker0: port 2(vethfd09262) entered disabled state
[1568502.681529] docker0: port 2(vethfd09262) entered disabled state
[1568502.682111] device vethfd09262 left promiscuous mode
[1568502.682113] docker0: port 2(vethfd09262) entered disabled state
[1568503.037301] aufs au_opts_verify:1612:docker[25411]: dirperm1 breaks the protection by the permission bits on the lower branch
[1568503.071988] aufs au_opts_verify:1612:docker[25370]: dirperm1 breaks the protection by the permission bits on the lower branch
[1568503.102768] aufs au_opts_verify:1612:docker[4932]: dirperm1 breaks the protection by the permission bits on the lower branch
[1568503.103562] device veth6cd39d2 entered promiscuous mode
[1568503.103649] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): vethffd65cb: link is not ready
[1568503.103702] docker0: port 2(veth6cd39d2) entered forwarding state
[1568503.103706] docker0: port 2(veth6cd39d2) entered forwarding state
[1568503.103719] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): vethffd65cb: link becomes ready
[1568503.146365] eth0: renamed from vethffd65cb
[1568518.132006] docker0: port 2(veth6cd39d2) entered forwarding state
```

**Docker info :**

```
Containers: 40
Images: 538
Storage Driver: aufs
 Root Dir: /var/lib/docker/aufs
 Backing Filesystem: extfs
 Dirs: 618
 Dirperm1 Supported: true
Execution Driver: native-0.2
Logging Driver: json-file
Kernel Version: 3.19.0-25-generic
Operating System: Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS
CPUs: 8
Total Memory: 31.29 GiB
Name: crosspromo-inpgngno01.xxxxxxx
ID: EOO2:DMGR:POHZ:VLKM:6KKZ:DX6S:5XIN:X4DA:22HH:L62N:FCI5:O32P
WARNING: No swap limit support
```

**uname -a**

```
Linux crosspromo-inpgngno01.xxxxxxx 3.19.0-25-generic #26~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jul 24 21:16:20 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

So: Is that docker problems, or maybee uplink interface is broken?

Comment: That's ... quite bizarre. Have you considered using something other than Ubuntu?

Comment: Which messages in dmesg correlate to the times at which the network froze?

Comment: Confirm this issue, if qty of started docker containers more then 80

Comment: , and using --net=container:CID for the each 2 or 3 containers.

Comment: I can also reproduce this. Did someone find the solution?

Answer (score -1):

**You're running a system that is known to NOT work with Docker.** 
Judging by the error, it is simply crashing the system, repeatedly.

- AUFS is unstable and known to cause kernel panics.
- Ubuntu 14 is running an old kernel that's missing critical components for containerization
- Old version of Docker, ridden with bugs.

You can start by upgrading to Ubuntu 16.04 TLS (the latest as of writing this). Good luck to get Docker to work, the default setup usually doesn't.

**Basically, Docker is utterly broken and unstable on most systems. See these articles for the long and dramatic version.**

- https://thehftguy.com/2016/11/01/docker-in-production-an-history-of-failure/
- https://thehftguy.com/2017/02/23/docker-in-production-an-update/

Comment: That wasn't true when thehftguy wrote it in 2016, and is even less true today. Still, I can't imagine trying to host docker on a 14.04 system.